# Network Error: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: firewall, telnet

I'm trying to bootstrap a server via Chef (using winrm), but continue to get the message:
    Network Error: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

I've opened the port (5985) on the remote server (the firewall even shows as being turned off) but I still cannot access it, even with telnet. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured this out - the issue is that I didn't run the following command on the remote server:

`winrm quickconfig`